# Three.js weird crashes using spotlight

Tags: javascript, three.js, crash, shader

I am rendering some meshes and a plane in a 3D view using Three.js. I added a spotlight to the scene and since adding this I have been encountering weird crashes on Firefox. The scene actually renders fine when you load the page the first time. When refreshing the page, firefox crashes. I managed to screenshot the firebug console errors before it crashed:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 1285 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Failed to create D3D shaders. 
THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.
```

This is my spotlight code:

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
    spotLight.position.set( 2000, 1500, 300);
    spotLight.distance = 3000;
    spotLight.penumbra = 1;
    spotLight.intensity =2;
    spotLight.angle = 1.05;                     
    spotLight.castShadow = true;                
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 4096;
    spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 4096;             
    spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
    spotLight.shadow.camera.fov = 3000;
    scene.add(spotLight );
```

The weird thing is: it only crashes the second time the page is loaded, never on the first load! When I delete the code for the spotlight, it does not crash anymore. In google chrome it seems to work fine.

Comment: What materials are you using in the scene?

Comment: @2pha One texture material, on multiple meshes. I merged most meshes, so in the end there's only 3 meshes in the scene, of which only 2 actually cast shadows.

Comment: Textures and Materials are not the same. Materials are MeshStandardMaterial, MeshPhongMaterial, MeshLambertMaterial,  etc. you have not included enough here to determine the problem.

Comment: Well, one of the 3 meshes uses a `new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: groundTexture } );` and the other two use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: woodTexture } )`

Comment: Like I said, you have not included enough of your code to determine the problem. Edit your original question and include more code